# How to remove this bubble (Indicator light) in action bar tab in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-styles

How to get rid of these bubble shown in below figure. I have two tabs in my layout and I have used green indicator light to show selected tab (First tab is selected in below figure), which is working fine. But I don't know why that small bubbles (shown in below figure) are coming in both tabs. These small bubble indicator lights are always ON irrespective of tab selected/unselected. Any help?

[image: Layout Snapshot]

Here are my **style.xml** file -

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/RActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/RActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbartextcolor</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/RActionBarTabs</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/RActionBarTabBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">#99e9d1f6</item>
</style>

<style name="RActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">

    <item name="android:background">@color/actionbarbackgndcolor</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/RActionBarTitleText</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar title text -->
<style name="RActionBarTitleText" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbartextcolor</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar tabs text styles -->
<style name="RActionBarTabText" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbartextcolor</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>

<style name="RActionBarTabs" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView">

    <!-- tab indicator -->
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_bar_background</item>
</style>

<style name="RActionBarTabBarStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/actionbarbackgndcolor</item>
</style>
```

**@drawable/tab_bar_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- UNSELECTED TAB STATE -->
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"><layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <!-- Bottom indicator color for the UNSELECTED tab state -->
        <item android:left="-5dp" android:right="-5dp" android:top="-5dp"><shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/actionbarbackgndcolor" />
            </shape></item>
    </layer-list></item>
<!-- SELECTED TAB STATE -->
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"><layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <!-- Tab background color for the SELECTED tab state -->
        <item><shape>
                <solid android:color="@color/actionbarbackgndcolor" />
            </shape></item>
        <!-- Bottom indicator color for the SELECTED tab state -->
        <item android:left="-5dp" android:right="-5dp" android:top="-5dp"><shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/actionbarbottomindicatorcolor" />
            </shape></item>
    </layer-list></item>
```

actionbarbottomindicator color = "green", 
actionbarbackgndcolor = "blue" (action bar color shown in figure)

Edit: Also I have found that length of blue indicator line (My problem) is equal to length of tab title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with text background colour and it was set as blue. That's why blue bubble indicator light was increasing and decreasing by changing word length of tab title text.